# Simplest way to plot a vertical line on Indicator windows using Expert Advisor MQL5

Tags: c, mql5, metatrader5

I am trying to plot a vertical line on the indicator window with its values. I came across `OBJ_VLINE` while reading the documentation. But the example is too hard to understand.
I have plotted the adx on the chart using the following expert:
input int Candles_for_adx = 5;
input color maincolor_adx = Yellow, dpluscolor_adx=Lime,dminuscolor_adx = Red;

```
 void OnInit()
    {
    ChartIndicatorAdd(0,(int)ChartGetInteger(0,CHART_WINDOWS_TOTAL), 
 iCustom(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1,"ADX",Candles_for_adx,maincolor_adx,dpluscolor_adx,dminuscolor_adx) );
    }
```

I got the following in my output:
[image: output image]

What I am expecting to achieve:

[image: expected image]

How to write simple statements taking the coordinates and then plot the line?

Answer (score 0):

and what is the problem? vertical line is infinite, it has one parameter (`OBJPROP_TIME` or `OBJPROP_TIME1`) and no *PRICE* paramters.
What you have on the chart is `TREND_LINE`, it is a line that has its start (`OBJPROP_TIME1`,`OBJPROP_PRICE1`) and end(`OBJPROP_TIME2`,`OBJPROP_PRICE2`) and `ObjectSetInteger(0,name,OBJPROP_RAY,false);`.

So after adding `ADX` to the chart (by the way, why it has so many parameters? is it a custom ADX? if so, please make sure you called it correctly), draw the lines using `ObjectCreate(0,name,subwindow,0,0)` and set all its parameters (color, start and end point, RAY=false, width and some other parameters) after checking that object is created successfully.
Maybe you will need a special function `ObjDrawTrendLine(const string name,const int subwindow,const datetime dtStart,const double dStart,const datetime dtEnd,const double dEnd,const color clr)` that will draw such objects, or move them if name is same. Subwindow should be received from `CHART_WINDOWS_TOTAL` or externally.

Comment: Have you seen the image I have mentioned in my question? If you can tell me solution for that condition then it will be excellent...

Comment: yes I saw the charts you attached. and as i told you, you drew trend lines not vertical lines, so please decide what you really need - vertical or trend lines, first, and then Create objDrawTrendLine() function, if you have problems with it - please show what you did and hwat is the problem